# Is it possible to use iPhone Tethering with two computers at the same time?

Tags: iphone, tethering

Is it possible to use iPhone Tethering with two computers at the same time?

- ...one computer plugged in the USB
- ...and the other through bluetooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from experience, you can only do it through one connection and USB takes dominance over Bluetooth connection. If you know how to do Internet Connection Sharing (ICS), you can easily share your iPhone's connection through your computer's wireless device.

Answer (score 1):

If you tether the iPhone to one computer that has a wi-fi card you could set up an ad-hoc network and both computers could access the internet at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect the two computers by some other means, you could share the Internet connection from the tethered computer to the other one.

For example, if your tethered computer is a Mac, you can enable Internet Sharing via the Sharing panel in System Preferences. Then you can share the connection via wired ethernet, FireWire, computer-to-computer (ad-hoc) Wi-Fi, or possibly Bluetooth.

I'm fairly sure a similar option is available on Windows though I can't tell you precisely where to go clicking.

Answer (score 1):

I have just done this.. Connected my iPhone to PC through USB and to Mac through Bluetooth... Worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

If your iPhone happens to be jailbroken, there is an applicaation out there on Cydia called, [PdaNet](http://www.junefabrics.com/iphone/index.php). It has a Wifi Router Mode where from my experience allows multiple devices connected. I'm not sure about USB and Bluetooth but if your computer doesn't have a network adapter, there are plenty USB and PCI ones.